# LDAP - Spring Boot |Getting javax.naming.CommunicationException | Connection Refused

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am using `unboundid-ldapsdk` As a LDAP Server. Getting Connection Refused When I try to Access My Rest End Point. I have Set up Port in My `application.properties` file.
I've tried to run ldap sever on different Ports but Still getting the Same Error.
My Properties file Look Like this.

```
spring.ldap.embedded.port=3268
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:ldap-data.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.base-din=dc=springframework,dc=org
```

And My `LDIF` File Looks Like this that is copied from `https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/`

```
dn: dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: springframework

dn: ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: space cadets

dn: ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: "quoted people"

dn: ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: otherpeople

dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: $2a$10$c6bSeWPhg06xB1lvmaWNNe4NROmZiSpYhlocU/98HNr2MhIOiSt36

dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword

dn: uid=joe,ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Joe Smeth
sn: Smeth
uid: joe
userPassword: joespassword

dn: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Mouse, Jerry
sn: Mouse
uid: jerry
userPassword: jerryspassword

dn: cn=slash/guy,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: slash/guy
sn: Slash
uid: slashguy
userPassword: slashguyspassword

dn: cn=quote\"guy,ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: quote\"guy
sn: Quote
uid: quoteguy
userPassword: quoteguyspassword

dn: uid=space cadet,ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Space Cadet
sn: Cadet
uid: space cadet
userPassword: spacecadetspassword



dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=managers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: managers
ou: manager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=submanagers,ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: submanagers
ou: submanager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
```

Class that Extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people").groupSearchBase("ou=groups").contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:3268/dc=springframework,dc=org").and().passwordCompare().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
    }
}
```

And a simple Rest EndPoint.

```
@RestController
public class HomeResource {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayhello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I've looked everywhere but still not able to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I had 2 entries in pom.xml for unboundid-ldapsdk due to which i was getting the same javax.naming.CommunicationException | Connection Refused. Solution is to keep only the one dependency without scope=test.

**Problem:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Solution:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in application.properties.
Changed this

```
spring.ldap.embedded.base-din=dc=springframework,dc=org
```

to

```
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
```